# My java program won't run properly.

Tags: java, arrays, variables, while-loop

I'm a java beginner and I have written this code:

```
class Friends {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] facebookFriends = { "John", "Joe", "Jack", "Lucy", "Bob", "Bill", "Sam", "Will" };
        int x = 0;
        while (x <= 8) {
            System.out.println("Frind number " + (x + 1) + " is " + facebookFriends[x]);
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println("");

        if (facebookFriends.length < 5) {
            System.out.println("Where are all you're friends?");
        }
        else if (facebookFriends.length == 5) {
            System.out.println("You have a few friends...");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You are very sociable!");
        }
    }    
}
```

When I run the program it reads the names correctly but it doesn't display any of the text such as "You have a few friends..." or "You are very sociable!" Also, when I run it says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8" between the third and forth name. I don't know what's wrong with my code but I would be grateful if anyone could tell me the problem. Thank you.

Comment: An array goes from 0 to length-1

You have to do `while(x < 8)` because your length is 8

Comment: you do not get the error between the third and the forth. You get the error after the last one. It is just that the error stream get's printed before the the fourth one get's printed on the standard output stream. after every `System.out.println(...)` you could do a `System.out.flush()`  (flush means print right now instead of when the buffer is full) to see this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x <= 8` should be `x < 8`.

The `facebookFriends` array has 8 elements (having index from `0` to `7`). Trying to access any position beyond this range will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

Comment: THANKYOU SOOOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH! I can't believe I didn't see that!

Answer (score 5):

```
while (x <= 8) {
   System.out.println("Frind number " + (x + 1) + " is " + facebookFriends[x]);
   x++;
}
```

tries to eventually read `facebookFriends[8]`. This is impossible as it goes from 0 to 7.

Use:

```
while (x < facebookFriends.length) {
```

instead.

Comment: Even better would be `while (x < facebookFriends.length)`. Don't use magic numbers.

Answer (score 3):

`while (x <= 7)`  instead of  `while (x <= 8)`

Arrays in Java, start from 0 and not 1.

If you look at the exception :

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   8"

It tells you what went wrong.

Comment: Generally with arrays it's better in my opinion to use `i<length` as opposed to `i<=(length-1)` as it's slightly more readable.

Comment: Right, even I like that better, don't know why I used this :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, it should be `x <= 7`, `x < 8` or better `x < facebookFriends.length`, as Java arrays are zero (0) based.

Another way of writing the code would be:

```
class Friends 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] facebookFriends = { "John", "Joe", "Jack", "Lucy", "Bob", "Bill", "Sam", "Will" };

        int length = facebookFriends.length;
        int num = 1;
        for ( String friend: facebookFriends )
            System.out.println("Friend number " + (num++) + " is " + friend);

        System.out.println("");

        if (length < 5)
            System.out.println("Where are all your friends?");
        else if (length == 5)
            System.out.println("You have a few friends...");
        else
            System.out.println("You are very sociable!");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if u really want to make it general purpose use
while(x<=facebookFriends.length)
this will ensure it works well even if number of friends in array are increased or decreased